# How to ignore bad images in iraf imstat

Tags: flat-file, astropy, astronomy, fits, iraf

Suppose I have three fits images (file1.fits, file2.fits, and file3.fits).The middle one(file2.fits) is a bad image. When i run imheader it shows [![result]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6lEp.png)

`file1.fits[1092,736][ushort]: bias`

`file2.fits[1092,736][ushort]: ASAS135406`

`file3.fits[1092,736][ushort]: flat`

But when i run imstat it shows [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEec2.png)

`ERROR: Pixel storage file is truncated (file2.fits)`

It gave the result for the first image, but the execution stops as soon as it encounters a bad file. How to ignore the bad file and continue the execution

Comment: It sounds like you have two choices: 1) download the source code for imstat and modify it so that it continues,or 2) write a little shell script that calls imstat for one file at a time, in a loop.

Comment: I have done it by putting the imstat command in try except block. Thankyou for your response.

Comment: Q: If you use a try/catch block ... doesn't your app stop processing files at the first file that fails?  Maybe the app itself doesn't crash anymore ... but don't you want it to look at the rest of the files, too?

Comment: no sir it does not fails..as soon as i encounter the bad file in catch block, i move that file to another directory.

Comment: If you pass a wildcard (`imheader *.fits`)... and if file 2 of 3 is "bad"... then it never gets to file 3, correct?

Comment: if i do it in terminal then it stops at file 2, but if i do with   try catch it shows a error that file 2 is bad then shows header for file3.